# Display: flex with list navigation IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, display

I've searched and searched and tried so many things but I don't have a good enough grasp on what I'm doing to work out where I'm going wrong with this.

I have a list.

```
    <div class="topNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="MODL.html" title="HSE">HSE</a></li>
            <li><a href="MODL-PROC.html" title="PROCESSING">PROCESSING</a></li>
            <li><a href="MODL-UG.html" title="UNDERGROUND">UNDERGROUND</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.topNav {
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
}

.topNav ul {
  background: #eee;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 80%;
}
.topNav a {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.topNav a:hover {
  background: #d4d4d4;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
 .topNav ul {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

It does exactly what I want in Chrome. But IE11 stacks each list item one on top of the other. So far I can't get them to run in one row.

There's nothing else in the CSS that affects ul/li's and only text-align:center; and height:100% set to the body.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Sam

Comment: in my IE 11 , everything works fine with the provided code. Maybe something else is interfering ? https://jsfiddle.net/767x4qf8/1/

Comment: same here, given code works fine in IE11 as display:flex is supported

Comment: Oh really? That would explain a lot..
Any ideas what could be causing me issue?

Comment: Haha! This is doing my head in!
This is what I want, working fine in Chrome - http://imgur.com/h9hHv3Z
But any version of IE (via F12 Emulation) - http://imgur.com/T9FrcGe is a no go

Comment: Ok with further testing - the JSFiddle works fine in my IE. Weird.
If I change the "Document Mode" in IE developer tools I can get it to work in Document mode 10 and 11 perfectly. I don't know what this is telling me though

Comment: I've now tested it outside of our work network. It appears to be something to do with IE here on site.
If anyone has any ideas I'd love to hear them. Otherwise it's not really a code issue anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Using

`display:inline-flex;`

solved it.